# AutoMapper in C# Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, automapper

i have a class

```
public class Order
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public Nullable<int> StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class StatusDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

autoMapper:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>().ReverseMap(); 
cfg.CreateMap<Status, StatusDto>().ReverseMap();
```

In model classes I was able to do this:

```
name = order.status.Name
```

How can i achieve that when using autoMapper

Comment: I am afraid I am completely unable to make sense of this question. Please have a look into [ask] and improve the question. What exactly do you want to do and how does what code fail when you try to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OrderDto` does not have `Status`, so you can not get `Status` name from mapped object.

So either you will create new property in `OrderDto` class `StatusName`, and map it to `status.name` of your model, or add to `OrderDto` object `StatusDto` field, like this:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StatusId { get; set; }
    public StatusDto Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then AutoMapper will map models's `Status` field to `OrderDto`'s `Status` field.

Comment: i tried adding status property to orderDto and it worked :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you need to define it in mapper profile.

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.name, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.status.Name));
```

Comment: i want all properties of status to be accessible in orderDto so i tried putting statusDto property in orderDto as mentiond by @kosist and voila .. it worked